# Proxy cannot be cast to TestBenchElement - WebElement to TestBenchElement

Tags: java, selenium, vaadin, pageobjects, test-bench

I'm building a Page object pattern framework for a Vaadin front-end using their official UI testing tool, TestBench (based on Selenium).

Using the PageFactory, the Page objects are able to lazily locate the web elements that I need the tests to interact with but they do not allow for casting to TestBench elements.

There are quite a few convenience methods built around specific Vaadin components that I wish to use but receive a class cast exception.

Example:

```
public class TestPage extends TestBenchTestCase {

  private WebElement button;

  public String getText() {
      TestBenchElementCommands testElement = testBenchElement(button);
      ButtonElement btn = testElement.wrap(ButtonElement.class);
      btn.getCaption();
  }

}
```

Results in this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6 cannot be cast to com.vaadin.testbench.commands.TestBenchElementCommands

I'm using the provided methods from TestBenchTestCase to cast and wrap the element.  While getting Button text isn't the best example there are many [methods](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin-testbench-core/4.0.0.rc1/com/vaadin/testbench/TestBenchElement.html) that would be nice to have just in the superclass alone.

This issue exists whether I use PageFactory or new instantiation for a Page.

The WebElement is able to be located as a check on isDisplayed() returns true.

Runtime type is an instance of TestBenchElement:

> com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchElement_$$_javassist_1@3a96d74

I guess the question boils down to, is this possible?  Or does TestBench only work with Page object pattern at the Selenium level (WebElement) ?

If thats the case then the additional cost for a license could be saved.

Comment: Please post the HTML for the button and add the code for the locator for the button.

Comment: There is no explicit HTML written by myself for the button.  I'm using the Java GWT component Button provided with Vaadin to generate the CSS/HTML.  In this example, the default is used for the locator in which the PageFactory assumes the name of the field is the id or name. Apologies for not being explicit.

Comment: It's been some time since I last used TB, but unless something changed and if I recall correctly, you should be able to access your components easily using the [$ accessor](https://github.com/vaadin/testbench/blob/master/vaadin-testbench-core/src/main/java/com/vaadin/testbench/AbstractHasTestBenchCommandExecutor.java) (for a lack of a better term). Something along the lines of `$(ButtonElement.class).caption("My button").first().click()`. Did you already go over the [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/testbench/testbench-tutorial.html)? (there's also a github link for actual examples)